# cropping an image in css, maintaining aspect ratio and centered

Tags: css, html, image

Fitting a image into a div and maintaining the aspect ratio isn't that hard. But trying to keep the selected area in the center of an image is the hardest part.
What happens is that the image will zoom out to the top-left, while I want it to stay in the center, because people often take pictures where the biggest attraction is in the center of a photo.

This is the code I use now:

```
.cover-photo {
width: auto;
height: 60vh;

background-color: lightgray;

position: relative;
margin: 60px 0 0 0; //There is a header above this div

overflow: hidden;
background: url('../Img/cover_photo.jpg') no-repeat center center;
background-size: cover;}
```

It's supposed to be like a cover photo of a facebook profile. If you have any suggestions or solutions, I would like to hear them.

Answer (score 0):

**You can use different kind of approch instead of worrying about which area should I zoom?  use jquery image cropper(there are many this kind of [plugins](http://www.jqueryrain.com/demo/jquery-crop-image-plugin/) )**

## demo

**https://github.com/scottcheng/cropit/**

Comment: It's not about cropping a photo and downloading it afterwards. It's more about uploading and forgetting about it. It's kind of like a cover photo on your facebook profile.

Comment: before upload users can crop it and remove unnecessary parts using above plugin  and after that they can upload images to server